# explain the "extras" part of a CKAN Apache Solr search query

Tags: solr, geospatial, ckan

I am using the Python [ckanapi](https://github.com/ckan/ckanapi#ckanapi-python-module) to assess the spatial search ability of CKAN instances.

However there is trouble finding documentation for the "extras" part of the query.

http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/api/index.html#ckan.logic.action.get.package_search
does not mention "extras" in the list of available search parameters.

This query does work ...
{"q": "water AND metadata_modified:[2014-06-01T00:00:00Z TO NOW]",
 "rows": 2, "extras": {"ext_bbox": "-87,24,-80,31"}, "fq": "res_format:WMS"}

So would someone please explain the "extras" parameter, and the "ext_" prefix, and how one knows what other fields are available (e.g. maybe ext_crs and others).

-David

Answer (score 0):

A concise search found this:
https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/master/ckan/logic/action/get.py
which indicates that any parameter beginning with "ext_" can be expressed at the top-level of the query and is automatically moved into the "extras" dict.

Still looking for the overall answer regarding the "extras" parameter.